# WPF C# Touch doens't work until the 11th touch

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, touch, stylus

I've made an application, for self service, a KIOSK app. The product list is generated programmatically. On every window the program works fine on touch screen. Except for one window, where I have to touch exactly 10 times before it starts to work. I've tried to remake that window, I've put only one button on it, but it's the same. If i disable stylus and touch support with:
`<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Input.Stylus.DisableStylusAndTouchSupport=true"/>`
than it works. But this disables touch scrolling which is necessary for good user experience.
If i use touchdown or something similar it works, but I have `CheckBox` and `RadioButton` on that window, and I couldn't catch any Touch event on them. Any ideas?

Even if I clean everything from my code, or I create a new window with the same name, it doesn't work...

This is my windows xml:

```
<Window x:Class="GestbalSelfSalePOS.ProdusComandaDetailsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GestbalSelfSalePOS"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ProdusComandaDetailsWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="BackButton_Click" Content="Button" Margin="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My CS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace GestbalSelfSalePOS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ProdusComandaDetailsWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ProdusComandaDetailsWindow : Window
    {
        public ProdusComandaDetailsWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I open this window:

```
new ProdusComandaDetailsWindow().ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: how about using an app like snoop (or register on your own) to check what is capturing the event?

Comment: I don't know that app, can you link it for me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing exactly the same. I found out that the culprit is `window.ShowDialog()`. If you try, just for testing, use just `window.Show()` it will work.
It seems to me that, since the calling thread is blocked on the `window.ShowDialog()`, the events related to touch are not processed/reouted. It works ok with the mouse.
Currently, I have found no solution, just a workaround (an annoying one):
When I show the new window, previously I set `Topmost=true` on the new window and `Topmost=false` on the parent. I also set, the on the new window, the owner to the caller, so I may set the owner Topmost to true, before closing the new window.

Comment: I also have a similar issue, unfortuately nothing I tried worked so far.