# WPF C# Touch doesn't work until the 11th touch in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, touch, touch-event

I've made an application, for Point Of Sale. In this App, I need to select an item from the item list which I showed in Datagrid. But the problem is touch is not recognized until the 11th touch. using a mouse is working fine. but I can't use the touch system.
am using vs2017 WPF C#, Any one knows the reason for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF C# Touch doens't work until the 11th touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71530238/wpf-c-sharp-touch-doenst-work-until-the-11th-touch)

Comment: It helps to find out all other tool's problems like buttons, textbox, etc. Not working in Datagrid